# Jscrollpane v2 on IPad : arrow buttons not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch, jscrollpane

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
                    showArrows: true,
                    scrollbarWidth :33,
                    hijackInternalLinks: true
                });
```

This is the code I call in my script to load jscrollpane. It works perfectly on any pc (any browser). But on the IPad, although scrolling while swiping the text works, using the arrows is a bit buggy, you can't press the buttons for long and scroll the whole text, instead the text scrolls one line at a time.

Is there a solution for this problem?
Thanks everyone